# wordpress footer.php - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

Tags: php, wordpress, footer

Im getting a,

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /clientdata/zeus-dynamic-1/c/a/careassess.com.au/www/wp-content/themes/wptheme_careassess/includes/footer.php on line 108

I was trying to remove a section from the footer of my clients site and I managed to break their entire footer. Specifically I was trying to remove the Paypal section under 'éngage'
 from line 12-18.

Can some tell me where the bug is? I've tried to read up about it buti don't know what I'm looking for.

```
<?php if( !$fm_is_home ){ ?>
<div id="footer_subscribe">
    <?php echo(apply_filters('the_content', '[contact-form 3 "defaultSubscribe"]')); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<div id="footer_container">     
<?php if( !$fm_is_home ){ ?>    
    <ul id="footerNav">
    <li<?php checkSelected($ENGAGE_ID); ?>>
            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($ENGAGE_ID); ?>"><span class="title">engage</span></a>
            <ul>
                <?php echo print_page_navigation($ENGAGE_ID, $PAYPAL_ID); ?>
            <li><?php $paypalPage = get_page($PAYPAL_ID); ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($PAYPAL_ID) ?>"><?php echo($paypalPage->post_title); ?> <img class="paypal" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/btn_paypal.gif" width="44" height="16" alt="paypal" title="paypal" /></a>    
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li<?php checkSelected($REFER_ID); ?>>
            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($REFER_ID); ?>"><span class="title">refer</span></a>
            <ul>
                <?php echo print_page_navigation($REFER_ID); ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li<?php checkSelected($DELIVER_ID); ?>>
            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($DELIVER_ID); ?>"><span class="title">deliver</span></a>
            <ul>
                <?php echo print_page_navigation($DELIVER_ID); ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li<?php checkSelected($SUPPORT_ID); ?>>
            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($SUPPORT_ID); ?>"><span class="title">support</span></a>
            <ul>
                <?php echo print_page_navigation($SUPPORT_ID); ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li<?php checkSelected($SHARE_ID); ?>>
            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($SHARE_ID); ?>"><span class="title">share</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="/category/news/">Our latest news</a>
                </li>
                <?php echo print_page_navigation($SHARE_ID); ?>
                <li>
                    <span class="follow">Follow us: 
                        <a href="<?php echo(get_option('twitter_link')); ?>" class="btn twitter"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/btn_twitter.gif" height="32" width="16" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter"/></a> 
                        <a href="<?php echo(get_option('facebook_link')); ?>" class="btn facebook"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/btn_facebook.gif" height="32" width="16" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook"/></a>
                    </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/footer_logo_careassess.gif" width="149" height="39" alt="Care Assess" title="Care Assess" />
            <span class="copyright">&copy; Copyright 2011 <strong>Care Assess</strong>.</span>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="/about-us/">About us</a></li>
            <li<?php if($current_post_ID == $TERMS_ID){ echo(' class="selected"'); } ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($TERMS_ID); ?>">Terms</a></li>
            <li<?php if($current_post_ID == $POLICIES_ID){ echo(' class="selected"'); } ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($POLICIES_ID); ?>">Policies</a></li>
            <li<?php if($current_post_ID == $AGREEMENTS_ID){ echo(' class="selected"'); } ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($AGREEMENTS_ID); ?>">Agreements</a></li>
            <li<?php if($current_post_ID == $DISCLAIMER_ID){ echo(' class="selected"'); } ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($DISCLAIMER_ID); ?>">Disclaimer</a></li>
            <li<?php if($current_post_ID == $FEEDBACK_ID){ echo(' class="selected"'); } ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($FEEDBACK_ID); ?>">Feedback</a></li>
            <li<?php if($current_post_ID == $CREDITS_ID){ echo(' class="selected"'); } ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($CREDITS_ID); ?>">Credits</a></li>
            <li<?php if($current_post_ID == $SITEMAP_ID){ echo(' class="selected"'); } ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($SITEMAP_ID); ?>">Sitemap</a></li>
            <?php if( $fm_is_home ){ ?>
                <li><span id="seoShow">More</span><span id="seoHide">Less</span></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <li<?php if($current_post_ID == $CONTACT_US_ID){ echo(' class="selected"'); } ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($CONTACT_US_ID); ?>">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>

        <?php if (!has_parent_page($SHARE_ID) && $SHARE_ID != $current_post_ID) { ?>
            <div class="controls">
                <form action="http://www.google.com/translate" id="language" target="_blank">   
                    <fieldset>
                        <input name="u" value="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" type="hidden" />
                        <input name="hl" value="en" type="hidden" />   
                        <input name="ie" value="UTF8" type="hidden" />   
                    </fieldset>   
                    <fieldset>
                        <img class="google_icon" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/google_icon.gif" width="19" height="20" alt="google" title="google" />
                        <select name="langpair" onchange="document.forms['language'].submit()">
                            <option value="en|en">English</option>
                            <option value="en|fr">French</option>
                            <option value="en|de">German</option>
                            <option name="langpair" value="en|it">Italian</option>
                            <option name="langpair" value="en|pt">Portuguese</option>
                            <option name="langpair" value="en|es">Spanish</option>
                            <option name="langpair" value="en|ja">Japanese</option>
                            <option name="langpair" value="en|ko">Korean</option>
                            <option name="langpair" value="en|zh-CN">Chinese Simplified</option>
                        </select> 
                    </fieldset>
                </form>  

                <ul>
                    <li class="addthisLi">
                        <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
                        <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
                            <a class="rss btn" href="http://www.careassess.com.au/feed/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/btn_addthis_rss.png" width="25" height="48" alt="RSS" title="RSS" /></a>
                            <a class="addthis_button_facebook btn"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/btn_addthis_facebook.png" width="25" height="48" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook" /></a>
                            <a class="addthis_button_twitter btn"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/btn_addthis_twitter.png" width="25" height="48" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter" /></a>
                            <a class="addthis_button_google btn"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/btn_addthis_google.png" width="25" height="48" alt="Google" title="Google" /></a>
                            <a class="addthis_button_email btn"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/btn_addthis_email.png" width="25" height="48" alt="Email" title="Email" /></a>
                            <!--<a class="addthis_button_compact btn"><img src="<?php
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've certainly learnt my lesson about editing theme files when your a noob :(

Comment: You codes are incomplete. Look at the last line.

Comment: Your file looks incomplete, probably lost data during saving/upload .

Answer (score 0):

You have to close if conditions,i doesn't saw whether it's has been closed and line `108` not fully shown in given link please can you give proper code.

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in last

```
 </div></li></ul>
   <?php } ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (!has_parent_page($SHARE_ID) && $SHARE_ID != $current_post_ID) { ?>
```

didn't see that being closed, unless I am mistaken.

Add:

```
<?php } ?>
```

To fix the issue!